# SSAS Data Source View Relationship

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012, ssas-2016

I need to get all the relationships in my SSAS cube Data Source View between Fact and Dim tables. I've around 15 Fact tables and linked dimensions to it. Is there any MDX query to get the relationship other then doing it manually

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you want to export a list of relationships between measure groups and dimensions as they are represented in the Dimension Usage tab of the cube designer. (The relationships in the DSV don't much matter unless SSAS needs to figure out how to join two tables in a SQL query it generates. You can have a cube with no DSV relationships at all. As long as the Dimension Usage tab has the right relationships then the cube will work.)

So please install the free BI Developer Extensions and run the [Printer Friendly Dimension Usage Report](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/PrinterFriendlyDimensionUsage/). I believe it will contain the info you need.

I would recommend the above. If you want to look at the appropriate data management view (DMV) run the [MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/schema-rowsets/ole-db-olap/mdschema-measuregroup-dimensions-rowset?) DMV. It is harder to use and interpret but has what you need in terms of representing the Dimension Usage tab:

```
Select * from $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASUREGROUP_DIMENSIONS
```